# Select2 - Infinite loop with trigger('change')

Tags: jquery-select2

Here is my case:

```
$('select').select2();

$('select').on('change', function () {
    // calling a function
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    // changes my select values
    // so I need to update the select for seing the news values
    $('select').trigger('change');

    // hehe I fire the change event so myFunction is called again and again
}
```

What can I do to avoid that behavior? Regards...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Select2. I had the same issue with the following code:

```
var FID = $(location).attr('href').split("/")[5];
$('#facility').children().each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == FID.trim()) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
    }
});
```

The following isn't ideal, but it does fix the issue. Note that you *will* need to redefine your Select2 options (mine shown).

```
var FID = $(location).attr('href').split("/")[5];
$('#facility').children().each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == FID.trim()) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('#facility').select2({
            placeholder: "",
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
        });
    }
});
```